# Including an image in an RDLC results in a unexpectedly large output size

Tags: image, optimization, pdf, reporting-services, rdlc

I have an RDLC report that has some data and (optionally) an image. The content is rendered to a PDF.

I may have a container (package) file where 100 of the same results are stored. The problem is that if I include the image, the result output increases at a larger amount than is expected.

As an example; My RDLC report is an invoice that can have an image at the bottom where a picture of a signature is displayed. I may have 100 invoices in a package file for a customer.

If the size of the total output package (100 invoices) without the image is 2MB, and the image is 15 KB, I would expect the total output package with the image to be in the neighborhood of 3.5MB (2MB + 15KB * 100). The problem is I am getting a total output package of over 8MB.

---

Are there any techniques that can be used to reduce the size of this output, or any other ways to go about getting an output size that is more congruent with expectations?

Comment: No idea what rdlc is. But I think a 15KB image does not necessarily have to be 15KB when rendered in a PDF. This is because a typical image made for web has a resolution of 72dpi. When included in a PDF, the software would typically convert it 200-300dpi for optimal print quality. A 100x100 px image thus becomes ~278x278px image at 200dpi; 10,000px image gets converted to 77,000px, you do the math.

Comment: It would be foolish for a PDF renderer to save upsampled images, since no new information is added.  Upsampling can wait until print time.  But plenty of software does foolish things...

Comment: Can you tell me type of your image (jpg, png, tif), its color depth (1bpp, 8bpp, 24bpp, etc) and its size (width and height in pixels)?

Comment: AFAIK PDF stores all internal images in TIFF format. Depending on your PDF generator's capabilities, it can very well be saved with little or no compression.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your PDF generator's capabilities, images can be saved with weak, lostless or even no compression. You can use the following method to extract image information from a PDF to check whether this is your case. If it is, some "[PDF compression](https://www.google.ru/search?q=PDF%20compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen%3aofficial&client=firefox)" software can be used to fix this.

(This may look odd, but I really didn't find any pre-written software that can do this)

Install Python 2.x and [PDFMiner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) package (refer to [PDFMiner manual#cmap](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html#cmap) for installation steps), then use the following code to list all images in a document, their sizes and compression. For list and explanation of compression algorithms used by PDF, see [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), p.23 ("Standard filters" table).

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice

# Open a PDF file.
fp = open('Reader.pdf', 'rb')
# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)
# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
doc = PDFDocument()
# Connect the parser and document objects.
parser.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(parser)
# Supply the password for initialization.
# (If no password is set, give an empty string.)
doc.initialize('')
# Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
if not doc.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
# Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTImage
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

# Set parameters for analysis.
laparams = LAParams()
# Create a PDF page aggregator object.
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

#Build layout trees of all pages
layouts=[]
for page in doc.get_pages():
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    # receive the LTPage object for the page.
    layouts.append(device.get_result())

#search the trees for images and show their info,
# excluding repeating ones
known_ids=set()
count=0;size=0
def lsimages(obj):
    global count; global size
    if hasattr(obj,'_objs'):
        for so in obj._objs:
            if isinstance(so,LTImage):
                i=so; id=i.stream.attrs['ID'].objid
                if id not in known_ids:
                    a=i.stream.attrs
                    print a
                    count+=1;size+=a.get('Length',0)
                    known_ids.add(id)
            lsimages(so)
for l in layouts:
    lsimages(l)
print "Total: %d images, %d bytes"%(count,size)
```

Credits: boilerplate code was taken from [Programming with PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html) article.